# What should I change to exit the loop?

Tags: for-loop, assembly, x86

I think I should change this line:

```
inc byte [nr]
```

to exit the loop, and my program should print 512.

```
%include "io.inc"
section .data
  nr: db 0x88, 0x1
section .text
  global CMAIN
  CMAIN: 
    for:
      inc byte [nr]
    jnc for
      inc byte [nr + 1]
      PRINT_UDEC 2, nr 
      xor eax, eax
    ret
```

Comment: If you look at an instruction set reference for the [INC](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INC.html) instruction you will see that INC doesn't alter the Carry flag. The instruction set reference says _**The CF flag is not affected**. The OF, SF, ZF, AF, and PF flags are set according to the result._ . Because of this your loop never end since you are using _JNC_ (Jump no carry). Maybe you want _JNZ_ (jump not zero) instead of _JNC_?

Comment: If you want to increment by 1 and set the Carry Flag you can use the [_ADD_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ADD.html) instruction like `add byte [nr], 1`

Comment: Side note. There are one of 2 possible outcomes for this code you have using _INC_. If the carry flag was clear before the loop started it will infinitely loop (this is likely what you are seeing), If it happened to be set before the loop then it would print 649 (0x200 + 0x89)

Answer (score 1):

When `nr` approaches the byte-limit of 255, the `INC` will surpass it and wraparound from 255 to 0.

Unfortunately the [`INC instruction`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/INC.html) *does not set* the `CARRY` flag on a wraparound - causing the endless loop, because `JNC`'s condition is always met.

So one solution would be changing

```
inc byte [nr]
```

to

```
add byte [nr], 1
```

which modifies the `?CARRY` flag. Then the whole algorithm should succeed as expected.

Comment: INC doesn't alter the carry flag (you can see my comment under the OPs question)

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yes. I suspected so while writing that answer, but didn't check it. I'm gonna fix my answer.

Comment: Yor answer is still inconsistent because you first tell the OP _This will go on until nr is 0FFh = 255. Then the INC will surpass the 8-bit-limit of 255 and set the ?CARRY flag, because a wraparound of 255 to 0 will cause that._

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Sorry for the delay, my internet connection went down for some time. Thanks for your corrections of my flawed answer.

Comment: I still like more the `jnc` -> `jnz` change as "solution" :) As `add` will compile to +1B longer machine code, so you can't "fix" that code in-place with `add`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you *can* change. So in such case:

```
%include "io.inc"
section .text
  global CMAIN
  CMAIN:
    mov   eax,512
    PRINT_UDEC 4,eax 
    ret   ; and not caring to return 0
```

Comment: I think at a minimum they were probably looking for a loop given the tag.

Comment: @MichaelPetch sure.. but wording your question properly is important and this code does also exit the (nonexistent) loop. QED

Comment: Sure. But I had investigated the source of the question before commenting. If you review this [lab link](http://ocw.cs.pub.ro/courses/iocla/laboratoare/laborator-07) and look at _[2p] 2. Increment flags_ you'll see what the intent was. The idea was without changing the operands, fix the loop by changing one line so it is no longer an infinite loop and prints 512 as a result. Using something like _JNZ_ would do the trick. I agree the question could be written much better.

Comment: @MichaelPetch *"by changing one line"* yeah. I've seen your `jnz` answer in comment, and I definitely like it and consider it the correct solution. This is just sort of trolling (although I would prefer "expand horizons" term) the OP, because he missed to provide vital information in his question, so you had to investigate even what is being asked, not just what is the answer.

Comment: I pretty much investigate all questions that smell like a tutorial or assignment. Most often people asking the questions here leave out the why and often specifics of what is being taught or asked for.